# How much RAM is written to disk on hibernation (Ubuntu 18.04)?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, ssd, hibernate

When a system with 96GB of RAM is hibernated under Ubuntu 18.04, will then all of the 96GB be written to the swapfile (assuming a swapfile) or just the amount of actually used RAM (e.g. 9.6GB, if only 10% of the RAM are in use)?

Explanation: I have a system with 96GB of RAM and the swapfile is located on a SSD. Do I need to worry that everytime I hibernate actually the full 96GB are written, although the majority of it does not hold any valuable information? The reason I am concerned about the amount of written data is the wear that the SSD might suffer from the writing of the data.

Comment: This is answered on out sister site: https://askubuntu.com/questions/50143/how-large-of-a-swap-partition-is-needed-to-hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to the Ubuntu man page for hibernate in 18.04 LTS.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/hibernate.8.html

It states that only the contents of what is currently in system memory are saved to disk so you should not have to worry about 96GB of stuff being written each time. From that link you will also want to read up on the hibernate.conf file that controls the behavior of hibernate.

A link to the hibernate.conf file is below

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/hibernate.conf.5.html